# MYSQL: INSERT INTO while also doing INNER JOIN in the same query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having trouble understanding how to write this MySQL query and a lot of the answers I've been able to find here don't seem to help a lot.

I have two tables with these rows:

```
units
-----------------
unit_id (INT)
unit_name(STRING)

surveys
-----------------
survey_id (INT)
parent_unit(INT)
```

I am trying to add a record to the surveys table. In my query, I know the `unit_name` of `parent_unit` but I need to find out what the `unit_id` is.

I have not worked with mysql in a while so I am having trouble creating an INNER JOIN that would replace `unit_name` with the corresponding `unit_id`.

This is what I have tried so far, but I think I am very far from the answer:

```
$unit_name = "unit1"

INSERT INTO surveys (parent_unit) 
SELECT * FROM units
INNER JOIN units ON $unit_name=units.unit_name
VALUES ("unit name") //This should be an INT
```

The result of this query would be:

```
survey_id | parent_unit
----------+------------
        0 |           0
```

As the `unid_id` for the `parent_unit "unit1" is 0, which we can see in the units table:

```
> SELECT * FROM units WHERE unit_name LIKE "unit1";

unit_id | unit_name
--------+----------
      0 |     unit1
```

I hope I explained myself enough to be understood.

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample  and the expected  result

Answer (score 1):

So start simpler. First, what is the query to find a unit id, given the unit name, from units? As an elementary query:

```
SELECT unit_id
FROM units
WHERE unit_name LIKE "the_unit_name_you_have"
```

So then we look at what you actually want to do: you need to build a survey record, and you have a unit name. Rather than doing a *full table join for every possible unit*, let's just repeat that exact select, and just drop that into the table:

```
INSERT INTO surveys (parent_unit)
SELECT unit_id AS parent_unit
FROM units
WHERE unit_name LIKE "the_unit_name_you_have"
```

(Also note that that `AS` is entirely optional, but can make things easier to track as human being)

Comment: Do I also need to specify the VALUES I then want to add?

Comment: But that's not what you're showing, so if you have a _different_ question, you should update your post to talk about exactly what it is you're trying to do, not something similar, or close enough to it. In the question you're asking, you're only inserting a single value for a single column: `parent_unit`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your explanation seems you need
a join between  a 'unit name' from units and a parent_id from sessions based on the relation between unit_id and parent_id

```
INSERT INTO surveys (parent_unit) 
SELECT unit_id 
FROM units u
INNER JOIN surveys  s ON u.unit_name = 'unit name' 
    and u.id = s.parent_unit
```